# Questions about design approach and technologies

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Since I spend most of my time on Stack Overflow and MSO, I'm already know my question is off topic on SO.  Since I don't spend nearly as much time on this site, I wanted to ask about whether a question was on-topic or not before actually asking it.

I am researching/designing a personal project that is going to involve a Windows Service (which I have zero experience with), and I am looking for feedback as to whether my design approach (which is not much more than block diagram at this point) is the best solution, or if there is a better way to approach it? It is definitely subjective, but I think it still would have a correct answer, and I'm pretty sure it meets the [Good Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) criteria

If it is on-topic, but potentially a borderline question, are there any suggestions on what I should include to ensure it stays on topic?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Asking for a critique of your design should be OK.

As should asking for help with specific aspects of the design you are stuck with.

The same rules on asking specific, answerable questions apply here as they do on Stack Overflow.